# Can a Rinnegan user use Mangekyou abilities?

Tags: naruto

Since Rinnegan is an "upgrade" of Sharingan, then it should be possible that all the techniques of Sharingan will be carried away to Rinnegan like the Mangekyou.

If not, then why?

Comment: i think it's a no. Nagato can't use mangekyo Sharingan even though his eye came from Madara.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To put it bluntly, no, the rinnegan cannot use mangekyou abilities. As you can watch in the anime, Madara can switch between Rinnegan and Sharingan because he awakened both.
Nagato only had the Rinnegan.

Basically, the Rinnegan isn't an upgraded Sharingan, it's what comes next, but it's a completely different eye.

Answer (score 6):

It is, since during Madara and 5 kages fight, Madara is able to cast genjutsu to raikage after looking into his eyes, though his eyes is seen as a sharinggan.

And he can still use Susanoo which is a Mangekyo ability.

Comment: Vond Ritz is right. The question refers to Rinnegan users in general, not to particular users. Nagato was unable to use the Mangekyo, or maybe was unaware of it. Either way, he was a Rinnegan user who was unable to use the Mangekyo.

Answer (score 4):

A Rinnegan user can use the Mangekyō Sharingan abilities, if the user

1. Has one eye with a *Mangekyō Sharingan* and one with a *Rinnegan* (as seen with Tobi).
2. Naturally awakened the Rinnegan after awakening the *Mangekyō Sharingan*. (as seen with Madara).

If you look at the wiki page of [Rinnegan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Rinnegan)(emphasis mine, not originally there in the wiki).

> When Madara was reincarnated by Kabuto Yakushi to fight the Allied
>   Shinobi Forces, Madara once again gained access to the dōjutsu **(Rinnegan)**; his
>   Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan was able to transform into the Rinnegan at
>   will **(Madara awakened Rinnegan during the last days of his life)**. Based on data collected over the years, Kabuto Yakushi and
>   Orochimaru theorised that because the Sharingan originated from the
>   Rinnegan, it was possible for the dōjutsu to change into the Rinnegan
>   as part of a "natural evolution". This is supported by the fact he
>   maintains his Susanoo while having his Rinnegan activated. Upon
>   reincarnation, Nagato also retained the Rinnegan.

Since Madara had awakened both the *Mangekyō* and *Rinnegan* in his life, he could switch between the two and use the abilities of both the *dōjutsu's*. But in the case of Nagato, as he was implanted with the *Rinnegan* itself, he could not switch between them and hence, was never able to use those abilities. This wiki excerpt should confirm it.

> While the powers of the Rinnegan remain intact upon implanting them in a new person, like Nagato and Obito Uchiha, only one who "naturally" manifests the Rinnegan, as in Madara Uchiha's case, is able to switch between the Rinnegan and Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan; otherwise, the Rinnegan is always activated.

Tobi had 2 different eyes, one with the *Mangekyō* (his own eye) and the other with the *Rinnegan* (which he took it from Nagato's body after his death), and that's the reason why he could use the abilities of both but only with one eye for each of it.

Answer (score 0):

While the powers of the Rinnegan remain intact upon implanting them in a new person, like Nagato and Obito Uchiha, only one who "naturally" manifests the Rinnegan, as in Madara Uchiha's case, is able to switch between the Rinnegan and Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan; otherwise, the Rinnegan is always activated.

Comment: if this is from the wiki, then please quote it and remove the number marks. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Rinnegan and Mangekyo Sharingan are two different eyes. Completely different. The Sage of Six Paths had the Rinnegan and divided his power to create the Senju and the Uchiha. The Uchiha got the Sharingan and the Senju got really strong chakra and life force (chakra basically). The only reason why Madara got the Rinnegan was because he put some of Hashirama Senju's cells in himself. Thus bringing together the power that the sage had divided. He then would attain the sage's eyes (Rinnegan). He is able to switch between them. The Rinnegan cannot use Mangekyo techniques and vice versa.

The reason why Nagato cannot switch between the different eyes is that they were transplanted into him in the Rinnegan form, and since they aren't his natural eyes, his control over them is limited. A good example of this is Kakashi: he cannot change the Sharingan Obito gave him into a normal eye. That is why he covers it up when he isn't using it. The one absolute thing I can tell you is that the Rinnegan and the Mangekyo Sharingan are two different eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the Rinnengan is the pen-ultimate version of the Sharigan, they can use its power without the need for the eye form itself.

Comment: Please could you add some details to ascertain your point. A link to an wiki page or some other reliable source would be good

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible ***however*** only if the rinnegan is with the original person for whom it is awakened. But for him  too he has to revert back to Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan to use its abilities, and if he wants to use abilities of sharingan then he has to revert back to sharingan.

An uchiha who has awakened his rinnegan has 5 types of eyes..

- normal Black pupils
- sharingan
- Mangekyou Sharingan
- Eternal mangekyo Sharingan
- Rinnegan

Comment: you left out the whole part about they half to have Hagaromo's chakra/be a direct ancestor of his. Also, the person doesn't actually "have" to be an Uchiha but would have to be directly related to that clan which doesn't necessarily mean he's actually an Uchiha (his grandma/grandpa could have married one of the most pureblood Uchiha's or something)

Answer (score 0):

The Rinnengan User Can Use The Mangekyo Techniques.. But Only If its the user who has awakened the Rinnengan .. As You see in **Madara's** And **Sasuke's** Case.. As Sasuke Awakened his Rinnengan (In Left Eye) By taking chakra from Hogoromo he could use his Amateratsu from his left eye ..

Comment: Can you refer to a source who prove it?